# Moonwalker visits an old church made of moon rock

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story featuring a moonwalker (I think James Irwin) who is on a speaking tour. One of the stops is near a church which according to legend is made from moon rocks.

The legend is about someone flying to the Moon in a chariot pulled by geese and returning with the rock.

The closing line has the moonwalker chiselling a small sample of rock off the church. When exposed to the air, the rock gives off the same smell he remembers from returning to the lander with moon dust on his spacesuit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suspect this is "[Moon-calf](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82516)", a short story by Stephen Baxter published in 1998. The main character in the story is Colonel James ("Jays") Holland (rather than Jim Irwin), a retired Apollo astronaut who indeed had been to the Moon. While visiting Godwin chapel in Hereford, he notices basalt in the wall of the building:

> I know basalts. All the damn Moon rocks we picked up were basalts.
> It’s just unusual for such an old building to feature such displaced
> materials. They didn’t have the haulage capability we have now …’

and as the OP remembers, notes its characteristic tang is similar to that of moon-rocks:

> pungent smell, the odour of wood-smoke, or maybe of gunpowder: it is
> the smell of Moondust, slow-burning in oxygen from Earth …

The Godwin chapel is named after Francis Godwin, bishop of Hereford, who wrote one of the first science fiction stories "[The man in the moone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_Moone)":

> The story is about how a man called Gonsales trains swans to carry him
> through the air. Twenty-five of them, each attached to a pulley, save
> him from a shipwreck. But the swans hibernate on the Moon, and carry
> Gonsales there …

In "The man in the moone", the protagonist is actually propelled by geese rather than swans, so this seems to be a slip by Baxter. In any case,
the implication is that Gonsales really did travel to the Moon back in the fifteenth/sixteenth century, although probably not by flying geese or swans.

Comment: Thanks for including the isfdb link. That lead me to the copy of Phase Space on my shelves. It's the first story.